# How to convert old query with implicit joins to use explicit joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join, azure-sql-database

I have an old query that was written for Powerbuilder, and I need to update it for a SQL Azure Server.

Old Query:

```
select distinct <a bunch of stuff>
  from table1 ii,
       table2 apc, 
       table3 ir, 
       table4 pt, 
       table5 cw, 
       table6 g, 
       table7 cd, 
       table8 cr,
       table9 pr,
       table10 tfl         
 where apc.production_coil_no = ii.production_coil_no 
   and apc.routing = pr.routing
   and pr.product_type_cd = pt.product_type_cd 
   and apc.grade = g.grade 
   and ir.inventory_reason_cd = ii.inventory_reason_cd 
   and ir.pes_cd = pt.pes_cd 
   and tfl.to_freight_location_cd = apc.current_location
   and pt.active = "Y" 
   and pr.active_flag = "Y" 
   and apc.coating_weight *= cw.coating_weight_cd 
   and apc.production_coil_no *= cd.production_coil_no
   and cd.defect_cd *= cr.defect_cd 
   and cd.reason_for_last_status_change = 'Y' 
   and ii.inventory_reason_cd in ("IS","EP")
   and (apc.snapshot in ("Y","P","E","S") or apc.sdi_produced = "N") 
   and ii.change_datetime <= dateadd(dd,-1,(case @customer_id when 11 then getdate() 
                                                when 16 then (case isnull(g.high_strength,"N") when "Y" then dateadd(dd,-1 + (case datepart(dw,getdate()) when 1 then -1 when 2 then -2 else 0 end),getdate()) else dateadd(dd,-1 + (case datepart(dw,getdate()) when 1 then -1 when 2 then -2 else 0 end),getdate()) end) 
                                                when 639 then (case g.nm_high_strength when "Y" then getdate() end) 
                                                        else (case isnull(g.high_strength,"N") when "Y" then dateadd(dd,-2 + (case datepart(dw,getdate()) when 1 then -1 when 2 then -2 else 0 end),getdate()) else dateadd(dd,-1 + (case datepart(dw,getdate()) when 1 then -1 when 2 then -2 else 0 end),getdate()) end) end)) 

   and ii.sfi_material_specification_cd in ("NONE","",null) 

union

select distinct <a bunch of stuff>
  from table1 ii,
       table2 apc, 
       table3 pt, 
       table4 cw, 
       table5 g, 
       table6 cd, 
       table7 cr, 
       table8 mms,
       table9 pr,
       table10 tfl 
 where apc.production_coil_no = ii.production_coil_no 
   and apc.routing = pr.routing
   and pr.product_type_cd = pt.product_type_cd 
   and apc.grade = g.grade 
   and ii.sfi_material_specification_cd = mms.material_specification_cd 
   and tfl.to_freight_location_cd = apc.current_location
   and pt.pes_cd = "P" 
   and pt.active = "Y" 
   and pr.active_flag = "Y" 
   and apc.coating_weight *= cw.coating_weight_cd 
   and apc.production_coil_no *= cd.production_coil_no
   and cd.defect_cd *= cr.defect_cd 
   and cd.reason_for_last_status_change = 'Y'   
   and ii.inventory_reason_cd in ("IS","EP")
   and (apc.snapshot in ("Y","P","E","S") or apc.sdi_produced = "N") 
   and ii.change_datetime <= dateadd(dd,-1,(case @customer_id when 11 then getdate() 
                                                when 16 then (case isnull(g.high_strength,"N") when "Y" then dateadd(dd,-1 + (case datepart(dw,getdate()) when 1 then -1 when 2 then -2 else 0 end),getdate()) else dateadd(dd,-1 + (case datepart(dw,getdate()) when 1 then -1 when 2 then -2 else 0 end),getdate()) end) 
                                                when 639 then (case g.nm_high_strength when "Y" then getdate() end) 
                                                        else (case isnull(g.high_strength,"N") when "Y" then dateadd(dd,-2 + (case datepart(dw,getdate()) when 1 then -1 when 2 then -2 else 0 end),getdate()) else dateadd(dd,-1 + (case datepart(dw,getdate()) when 1 then -1 when 2 then -2 else 0 end),getdate()) end) end)) 

   and ii.sfi_material_specification_cd not in ("NONE","",null)
```

I have tried to rewrite this, but my test data is not currently reliable, so I don't know if I wrote it correctly.

First Attempt:

```
select distinct <a bunch of stuff>  
  from table2 apc
    JOIN table1 ii
        ON apc.production_coil_no = ii.production_coil_no
    JOIN table3 ir
        ON ii.inventory_reason_cd = ir.inventory_reason_cd
    JOIN table9 pr
        ON apc.routing = pr.routing
    JOIN table4 pt
        ON pr.product_type_cd = pt.product_type_cd
        AND ir.pes_cd = pt.pes_cd
    JOIN table6 g
        ON apc.grade = g.grade
    JOIN table10 tfl /*might break here*/
        ON apc.current_location = tfl.to_freight_location_cd
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table5 cw
        ON apc.coating_weight = cw.coating_weight_cd
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table7 cd
        ON apc.production_coil_no = cd.production_coil_no
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table8 cr
        ON cd.defect_cd = cr.defect_cd
 where pt.active = 'Y' 
   and pr.active_flag = 'Y' 
   and cd.reason_for_last_status_change = 'Y' 
   and ii.inventory_reason_cd in ('IS','EP')
   and (apc.snapshot in ('Y','P','E','S') or apc.sdi_produced = 'N') 
   and ii.change_datetime <= dateadd(dd,-1,(case @customer_id when 11 then getdate() 
                                                when 16 then (case isnull(g.high_strength,'N') when 'Y' then dateadd(dd,-1 + (case datepart(dw,getdate()) when 1 then -1 when 2 then -2 else 0 end),getdate()) else dateadd(dd,-1 + (case datepart(dw,getdate()) when 1 then -1 when 2 then -2 else 0 end),getdate()) end) 
                                                when 639 then (case g.nm_high_strength when 'Y' then getdate() end) 
                                                        else (case isnull(g.high_strength,'N') when 'Y' then dateadd(dd,-2 + (case datepart(dw,getdate()) when 1 then -1 when 2 then -2 else 0 end),getdate()) else dateadd(dd,-1 + (case datepart(dw,getdate()) when 1 then -1 when 2 then -2 else 0 end),getdate()) end) end)) 

   and ii.sfi_material_specification_cd in ('NONE',null) 

union

select distinct <a bunch of stuff>
  from table2 apc
    JOIN table1 ii
        ON apc.production_coil_no = ii.production_coil_no
    JOIN table8 mms
        ON ii.sfi_material_specification_cd = mms.material_specification_cd
    JOIN table9 pr
        ON apc.routing = pr.routing
    JOIN table3 pt
        ON pr.product_type_cd = pt.product_type_cd
    JOIN table5 g
        ON apc.grade = g.grade
    JOIN table10 tfl /*might break here*/
        ON apc.current_location = tfl.to_freight_location_cd
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table4 cw
        ON apc.coating_weight = cw.coating_weight_cd
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table6 cd
        ON apc.production_coil_no = cd.production_coil_no
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table7 cr
        ON cd.defect_cd = cr.defect_cd
 where pt.pes_cd = 'P' 
   and pt.active = 'Y' 
   and pr.active_flag = 'Y' 
   and cd.reason_for_last_status_change = 'Y'   
   and ii.inventory_reason_cd in ('IS','EP')
   and (apc.snapshot in ('Y','P','E','S') or apc.sdi_produced = 'N') 
   and ii.change_datetime <= dateadd(dd,-1,(case @customer_id when 11 then getdate() 
                                                when 16 then (case isnull(g.high_strength,'N') when 'Y' then dateadd(dd,-1 + (case datepart(dw,getdate()) when 1 then -1 when 2 then -2 else 0 end),getdate()) else dateadd(dd,-1 + (case datepart(dw,getdate()) when 1 then -1 when 2 then -2 else 0 end),getdate()) end) 
                                                when 639 then (case g.nm_high_strength when 'Y' then getdate() end) 
                                                        else (case isnull(g.high_strength,'N') when 'Y' then dateadd(dd,-2 + (case datepart(dw,getdate()) when 1 then -1 when 2 then -2 else 0 end),getdate()) else dateadd(dd,-1 + (case datepart(dw,getdate()) when 1 then -1 when 2 then -2 else 0 end),getdate()) end) end)) 

   and ii.sfi_material_specification_cd not in ('NONE',null)
```

Note: I am replacing @customer_id with test values that I know are valid when I test this.

My question is: Did I rewrite this correctly? If not, how can I fix it?

Comment: Looks good afaict. I only checked half, assuming the part after the union is the same. Obviously I can't test it. Why do you think it _might break here_ on the join to tfl?

Comment: Looks okay to me. Do the query plans look the same?

Comment: @Turophile, I thought it might break there because I'm not sure how the ordering of an implicit join works.

Comment: @MattGibson, I've spent a little bit of time looking into query plans so that I can be confident in saying "I think so?"

Comment: I just found out from my boss that I need to tear out all but one table from this and that we only need to check three conditions, so all my work on this may have been wasted.